# Limits of the Universe: how can be sure about the size of unobservable Universe?

Tags: cosmology, universe

It is established by different observations a 13.4 Gyr and 93 Glyr diameter Universe. However, how can be sure about the size of the Universe if there are portions of it we can not see? Is due to recollapse due to gravity?

Comment: 1) this may have been a typo but the diameter is 93 *billion* ly. You're missing a small factor of a billion. 2) That's the diameter of the *observable* universe. We know full well the entire universe is larger, but the unobservable stuff has no impact on us

Comment: Typos. Right. Giga factor lost, sorry

Comment: @Jim the two statements "We know full well the entire universe is larger", and "the unobservable stuff has no impact on us" put together don't really make much sense to me..

Comment: @JoshuaLin We know there's stuff that used to be in our observable universe but has, by now, passed outside of it. Thus we know the entire universe is larger than the observable one. Furthermore, anything beyond the observable limits is out of causal contact with us presently (and for the foreseeable future), which means it *has* no impact on us (I'm not saying it *had* no impact, just that it does not have any now)